# Define table in CASE Statement SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to set the variable using a case statement but I don't how to define the table which I want to run this statement.

```
DECLARE @Status varchar(50);
SET @Status = CASE
        WHEN id_tag = 'B4A63CDF' AND expiry> CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE) AND In_transaction = 0 AND blocked = 0
              THEN  'Accepted'
        WHEN id_tag = 'B4A63CDF' AND expiry > CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE) AND In_transaction = 0 AND blocked = 1
               THEN 'Blocked'
        WHEN id_tag = 'B4A63CDF' AND expiry> CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE) AND In_transaction = 1 AND blocked = 0
               THEN 'ConcurrentTx'
        WHEN id_tag = 'B4A63CDF' AND expiry< CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE) AND In_transaction = 0 AND blocked = 0
               THEN 'Expired'
               ELSE 'Invalid'
END
```

Here's the table. id_tag is unique.
[image]

Comment: Where did `id_tag` ,`expiry` columns be created? Could you give us more detail?

Comment: They are already in a table I just want to check those values and set the status variable according to that table.

Comment: Could you show us your table and what's your expected result if your table contains multiple rows?

Comment: @D-Shih I've updated.

Comment: You can just use `select ... from` with your `case when` expression

Comment: Can you show me how can I use with that?

Comment: A **variable** (as you used it) can contain a single value. From which row of which table (presumably you have more than just one) do you intend to use as a source for the assignment? In addition, CASE in tsql is an expression, not a statement. That is a significant difference from most other languages. Perhaps the "variable" usage is a red herring and you just want to select rows and include this case expression as a column within a resultset?

Comment: @SMor That's what I required

Comment: By the way you could combine these conditions `CASE WHEN expiry> CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE) THEN CASE WHEN ...`

Answer (score 1):

I think we can try to use `CASE WHEN` expression in `SELECT ... FROM` that might not need to use a variable to do that.

`T` can be instead of your really table name.

```
SELECT *,
    CASE
        WHEN id_tag = 'B4A63CDF' AND expiry> CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE) AND In_transaction = 0 AND blocked = 0
              THEN  'Accepted'
        WHEN id_tag = 'B4A63CDF' AND expiry > CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE) AND In_transaction = 0 AND blocked = 1
               THEN 'Blocked'
        WHEN id_tag = 'B4A63CDF' AND expiry> CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE) AND In_transaction = 1 AND blocked = 0
               THEN 'ConcurrentTx'
        WHEN id_tag = 'B4A63CDF' AND expiry< CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE) AND In_transaction = 0 AND blocked = 0
               THEN 'Expired'
               ELSE 'Invalid'
    END 
FROM T
```